# How to Add Javascript Code to Button to track the Clicks in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to add Pixel Event JavaScript Code to my WordPress site. I have added Code to the particular Page but now I want to Add JavaScript code to Button so that I can Track the Clicks.

I have added the JS Code for Pages in Header.php File in Wordpress as given Below:

```
<?PHP if(is_page('Page-name') : ?>
<script>
My Script
</script>
<?PHP endif ?>
```

Similarly, Can I Add JS code to Button to track the button Clicks?

Answer (score 0):

**Code to track which element was clicked**

```
var arrayWithElements = new Array();
document.onclick = clickListener;
function clickListener(e) {
var clickedElement;
if(e == null) {
    clickedElement = event.srcElement;
} else {
    clickedElement = e.target;
}
arrayWithElements.push(clickedElement)
alert(arrayWithElements);}
```

**Code that will be used on a identical HTML-page**

```
document.someHowGetTheElement().onclick();
```

Comment: I already have the JS code Provided by Facebook Pixel. I need to activate that code to a Particular Button in WordPress.